# VS2010 Access Violation while step the code using F10 or F11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a C++ native code that run fine in Debug and Release mode. But there is a little problem, if I debug my program and set a breakpoint in my code visual studio stop on breakpoint then if I press F5 to continue run code run normally but if I press F10 or F11 visual studio catch an AccessViolation and program will be stopped due to the fact that exception is not anywhere in my code and I don't handle it.

This error will not occure in Console application but in MFC application or when I use a .NET EXE to debug my native DLL.

I have a 64 bit Win7 and VS2010 SP1.

Comment: Are you mixing release & debug headers or libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry!! I found a solution, you must turn off Tools/Options/Debugging/Native/Enable RPC debugging.
and every thing will go fine. But I don't know if I want to debug RPC calls to external server, what should I do, so if any one help me and find the reason of failure it will be great